# Angular form is $valid when all inputs are blank, why?

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, required, angularjs-forms

My form is showing up as valid even though all of my input fields are blank.
I have the required keyword in the input fields.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.1/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <main>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <section ng-controller="LogInController as loginCtrl">
            <form name="signUpForm" action="/createuser" method="POST" novalidate>
              <fieldset>
              <div class="field input-field">
                Email <br />
                <input type="email" name="email" required />
              </div>

              <div class="field input-field">
                Password <br />
                <input type="password" name="password" required />
              </div>

              <div class="field input-field">
                Confirm Password <br />
                <input type="password" name="confirmation" required />
              </div>

              !! -- Form valid? {{signUpForm.$valid}} -- !!

              <div class="actions">
                <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
              </div>
              </fieldset>
            </form>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Loading this in the browser results in !! -- Form valid? true -- !!
I thought angular knows that the required tag makes a blank field invalid?

Comment: you have `novalidate` on form.

Comment: @maddog `novalidate` is needed so the browser doesn't perform it's validation.

Comment: @maddog Its just to avoid browser own validation popups like chrome does on required field

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should place `ng-model` on each field to enable form on each field,
Unless you add `ng-model` & `name` with value your field will never considered as part of your form. And do change one thing create one parent variable such as `form` & add all the scope variables in it. like in controller do `$scope.form = {};` & then on UI add all `ng-model` s to it like `form.email`, `form.password` & `form.confirmation`.

For more better form validation remove `action` & `method` attribute from a form & use `ng-submit` directive which will call one of controller method. & Do call post from that controller method by checking form is `$valid` or not.

**Markup**

```
<form name="signUpForm" ng-submit="submit(signUpForm, form)" novalidate>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="field input-field">
            Email
            <br />
            <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="form.email" required />
        </div>

        <div class="field input-field">
            Password
            <br />
            <input type="password" ng-model="form.password" name="password" required />
        </div>

        <div class="field input-field">
            Confirm Password
            <br />
            <input type="password" ng-model="form.confirmation" name="confirmation" required />
        </div>

        !! -- Form valid? {{signUpForm.$valid}} -- !!

        <div class="actions">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.submit = function(form, formData) {
    if (form.$valid) { //submit form if it is valid
        $http.post('/url', {
          data: formData
        })
        .success(function() {
          //code here
        })
        .error(function() {
        })
    } else {
        alert("Please fill all required fields")
    }     
}
```

Hope this has cleared your little concept about form, Thanks.

Comment: As you correctly state, each `<input/>` should get an `ng-model` attribute in order for the validation to work (the validators are added to the models). Yet you removed those attributes in your second edit of the answer …?