# Angular Form Not Submitting in Ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive

Hello i have a form inside a table row within an ng-repeat, inside that form i have a number field and a button(custom directive named "action") now when that button is clicked i want the form to do validation before submitting but when i try nothing happens i get no errors.

```
<table class="table schedules">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="text-align:center;" >&nbsp;Ticket Type</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;" >&nbsp;Ticket Price (GHS)</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;" >&nbsp;How many?</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @if (count($ticketTypes) <= 0))
    <tr ng-hide="d.ticketTypes.length > 0">
        <td style="text-align:center;" colspan="5">
            <h4 style="">There are no tickets available.</h4>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endif
    <tr ng-repeat="type in d.ticketTypes">
        <form name="ticketForm" ng-submit="ticketForm.$valid && addToCart('event', d, type.id, $index)" novalidate>
            <td style="text-align:center;" ><b><% type.fee_cat_desc %></b></td>
            <td style="text-align:center;" ><b><% type.event_fee | currency : '₵'  %></b></td>
            <td style="text-align:center;" ><b><input type="number" ng-model="line.d.ticket_no" class="form-control" min="1" max="30" style="width:80px !important;" ng-required/></b></td>
            <td>
                <action text='Buy Ticket' state='<% state %>' index='<% $index %>' selected='<% selectedIndex %>'></action>
            </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my action directive:

html:

```
<button type="submit" ng-class="{ 'btn-set': isReady === true || isWorking === true || isComplete === true || hasFailed === true, 'btn-ready-state': isReady === true || selected != index, 'btn-working-state': isWorking === true && selected == index, 'btn-failed-state': hasFailed === true }" ng-cloak>
    <i ng-if="isReady === true || selected != index" class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
    <img ng-src="/images/loading - small.png" class="img" ng-show="isWorking && selected == index "></span>
    <i ng-if="isComplete && selected == index " class="fa fa-check"></i>
    <span class="text">
        <span ng-if="isReady === true || selected != index"><% text %></span>
    </span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the thing you missed to `name=""` attribute on a form, it is needed to start form validation on field by angular

```
<input type="number" name="ticket_no-{{$index}}" ng-model="line.d.ticket_no" 
class="form-control" min="1" max="30" style="width:80px !important;" ng-required/>
```

Refer this [**SO Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544082/angular-form-is-valid-when-all-inputs-are-blank-why/29544157#29544157) for more Explaination

Answer (score 0):

You've got multiple `<form>`s with the same name. This is a problem for angular because it references each form by its name. A quick fix would be to use `$index` or `type` to make the names different.

```
<tr ng-repeat="type in d.ticketTypes">
    <form name="ticketForm_{{type}}" ng-submit="ticketForm.$valid && addToCart('event', d, type.id, $index)" novalidate>
        <td style="text-align:center;" ><b><% type.fee_cat_desc %></b></td>
        <td style="text-align:center;" ><b><% type.event_fee | currency : '₵'  %></b></td>
        <td style="text-align:center;" ><b><input type="number" ng-model="line.d.ticket_no" class="form-control" min="1" max="30" style="width:80px !important;" ng-required/></b></td>
        <td>
            <action text='Buy Ticket' state='<% state %>' index='<% $index %>' selected='<% selectedIndex %>'></action>
        </td>
    </form>
</tr>
```

Comment: This does not work either,please help me out, all i want to do is validate and submit each textbox on button click in my form.

Comment: I don't think the button submit works, is it because it is in a directive?

Comment: Take out `novalidate`, also remove this logic and put it into your `addToCart()` function instead: `ticketForm.$valid &&`

Comment: You also need a `name` on each of the inputs.

Comment: Can you make a plunker? That will make it easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have a input field with the `type="button"` and the `name="submit"`

Comment: I already have a submit button inside my form as shown in the html part of my code.

Comment: Yes, i see, but the name attribute of the button needs to be "submit". 
Like this: `<button type="submit" name="submit"></button>`.