# Login Validation Using Angular Js and JSP

Tags: java, angularjs, jsp, servlets, authentication

I am making an angular js - jsp application, for that I have created a login page, also I have created a servlet for  fetching database and comparing username and password. 
created login form and passed values my angular controller on login form submit. now I need to access the servlet that compares the login how do I pass information to servlet ? I have created a factory for that, also I have to use post method for passing datas.

I am pasting code til I have done.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

        <form name="myForm" novalidate class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <h2>{{login.username}}</h2>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" ng-model="login.username" required class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" required ng-model="login.password"  class="form-control input-lg"
                    placeholder="Password">

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid ||  
myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid"  ng-click="formSubmit(login)" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" value="Sign In"/>
                <span><a href="#">Need help?</a></span> <span class="pull-right"><a
                    href="#">New Registration</a></span>
            </div>

        </form>

    </div>
```

**Controller.js**

```
var appController = angular.module('appController', []);


appController.factory('AccountGroup', ['$resource', 'Data', function ($resource, Data) {
  return $resource( 
    {
      query: {
        isArray: true,
        method: 'POST'
      }
    }
  );
}]);

appController.controller('LoginController', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope,$http) {

      $scope.formSubmit = function(item) {
          debugger;
            console.log(item);
          };


}]);
```

This is my eclipse directory structure

[image]

LoginValdiator.java is the servlet used for login comparison

Comment: From your controller function "formSubmit" you need to call your servlet. Something like $http.post('login servlet url', item);. I am not familiar with Java backend but do you know the path to your servlet to perform the login?

Comment: @shivas actually I am also looking for the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a servlet,  add servlet mapping for that servlet  in the Deployment descriptor file(web.xml).

Eg :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.mycompany.test1</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/path/test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here you can access the servelet by .../path/test

Answer (score 1):

You missed to add `name` attributes on your form field which enables form validation rule on that field by angular.

**Markup**

```
<div class="container">

    <form name="myForm" novalidate class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <h2>{{login.username}}</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="login.username" required class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" name="password" required ng-model="login.password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid ||  
myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid" ng-click="formSubmit(login)" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" value="Sign In" />
            <span><a href="#">Need help?</a></span> <span class="pull-right"><a
                    href="#">New Registration</a></span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

For more information why name attributes are required, You can refer [**this Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29544157/2435473) by me only

Comment: thats fine, but I am not looking for frontend validation at this moment.

Comment: @ShajeerAhmd but surely it'd help you while doing front end validation'